# Visual C++ page navigation 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000

Tags: c++, pointers, visual-studio-2015

I recently started with Visual Studio's Visual C++, coming from a background in Code::Blocks C++ with OpenGL etc etc, so I like to think that I'm pretty good at programming.

Anyway, so there I was writing a Windows Phone 8.1 app, getting errors, fixing them etc etc, when I came across an "0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000." error.

After plenty of searching I discovered that it means that I'm dereferencing a pointer which hasn't yet been initialised.

The thing is, I've worked out the line which is throwing the error, and it's the one that Microsoft uses in every one of their navigation demos.

Here's the whole function:

```
void MainPage::newGameButtonClick(Object^ sender)
{
    // Go to new game page
    if (!this->Frame->Navigate(TypeName(NewGamePage::typeid))) {
         throw ref new FailureException("Failed to open New Game Page");
    }
    // Ensure the current window is active
    Window::Current->Activate();
}
```

Here's the specific line:

```
this->Frame->Navigate(TypeName(NewGamePage::typeid)
```

I can't find anything anywhere which says how to create/deal with this error sadly. Should I be initialising NewGamePage before hand? That wasn't the impression I got from the tutorials.

Thanks in advance!
 - Nick

Comment: Apparently either `this` or `Frame` is a null pointer. Using a debugger it should be easy to see which one. Then you have to look at the calling code and try to figure out WHY.

Comment: Ok, having screwed about with if statements, I've worked out that `Frame` is the null pointer here, but as I'm new to windows programming, I don't really understand the `Frame` class, and as such can't work out why it's a null pointer, or how to fix the problem (it seems to be partially read only)